# Using "prompts" on iOS Navigation Bars

Tags: mobile, ios, text, wording, prompt

**SOME CONTEXT**

In iOS, there is a standard text "prompt" element that can be added to a top NavigationBar like this:

[image: iOS Prompt]

I have released an app which has a list of car models that the user can select. If the car model that the user needs is not available, there is an 'Add' button on the Navigation Bar (top right) so that users can add their car model, select it and save.

**THE ISSUE AND QUESTION**

I have had a number of testers and users indicate that they did not know that they could add a new car model via the 'Add' button. This actually meant some people did not progress in using my app.

To resolve this issue, I wanted to use the iOS navigation bar prompt text item I showed above to explain to the user that they should select the car model from the list of it is already listed, but if the car model they need is not listed (ie. It is missing), then they can tap the 'Add' button to add the car model they need.

***What is the best way to WORD this for the prompt?***

My thoughts:

1. Select your car model or add a new one.
2. Tap 'Add' if your car model is missing.
3. Tap 'Add' if your car model is not listed.

***What do you think the most clear and concise way to word this is? (Can be one of my options or something different!)***

Answer (score 1):

Definitely the first one: "Select your car model or add a new one".
Maybe (when it isn't too long) you can optimize it to: "Select you car model or tap 'Add' if your car model is missing"

The problem with the 2nd and 3rd version of your texts is that you require that the user does not find his model and so does not even get the idea to looking for and applying directly a new one out of laziness.

**Formulate the text task-based:**

1st task is to look for own model!

AND ONLY WHEN IT IS MISSING the 2nd task: Tap "Add" to create a new one!

Comment: I like this logic - just waiting to see any other answers to viewpoints of people before marking any response as answer :)